# Разметка элементов html

Tags: html, css

Не получается разместить элементы таким образом. Как мне это сделать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пока получилось только добавить фон с красным градиентом и указатели влево/вправо
HTML

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="switch">
        <img src="img/left.png" >
        <img src="img/right.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.slider{
height: 360px;
background: url(../img/slider.jpg); 
}

.switch{
position: relative;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
width: 928px;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: кнопки next и prev позиционируйте position: absolute; right: 0; и left: 0; соответственно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно вот так, если хотите сделать слайдер, можно использывать готовые решения типа owl-carousel.

```css
.slider
    {widht: 100%; max-width: 1200px;}
    .switch
    {width: 10%;}
    .sw__left
    {float: left;}
    .sw__right
    {float: right;}
    .slide
    {width: 80%; float: left; text-align: center;}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/af54dc21f9.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
        <div class="switch sw__left">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
         <div class="slide">
            <img class="slide__img" src="http://svitoch.in.ua/upload/000/u8/002/2839cb71.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="switch sw__right">
           <i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
```